# How dangerous is Exploit.LNK.BadLnk.a (v)?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware

I have encountered a supposed low level eploit on my network at work, by the name of: Exploit.LNK.BadLnk.a (v). I have torn through pages of entries on google trying to find information on this bit of malware. The only entry that actually pertains to this one points to a report on www.sunbeltsecurity.com with an entry but no information on it or removal. So now I ask, has anyone here come across this one and successfully removed it?

Comment: There seems to be a distinct lack of information on this variant in any of the reputable and available databases that I have access to which is extensive. Can you tell me the name of the tool that you used which generated the name, or how you identified this - as often the naming convention can be slightly subjective.

Comment: This showed up in Quarantine via VMProtect, upon discovery we deleted but it keeps cropping up, throughout the network.

Comment: Are you using the VMPSoft version or the Acronis?

Comment: VMProtect, now owned by Shavlik not VMWare, for Malware active protection and Patching. We do use Acronis but only for imaging.

Comment: Yeah VMWare doesn't own it, just asked because VMPSoft has one and Acronis has one, just wanted to know which particular one you are using. So its the one from Shavlik, assuming Shavlik Protect then? I am trying to narrow it down so I can check their engine and see what's what.

Comment: That would be the one, though our UI still calls it VMProtect...even though we call it Shavlik Protect...

Comment: Gotcha, let me dig some and get back to you if I can get some information. Have you considered contacting their support or posting in their forum to inquire about this?